# Post "url-from' in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know from which url a form is send. I've tried  this, but the result is 'orgUrl' instead of the url where the form is send from.
Anyone an idea what's wrong with this code?

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value=orgUrl>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var orgUrl = window.location.href;
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to mix javascript with normal html which is not possible.
So you need to set the `value` also by javascript after getting the current url like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var orgUrl = window.location.href;
        $("#url").val(orgUrl );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ok thank you, this one works    <input type="hidden" id="url" name="url" value=orgUrl>